# Deep links to Facebook mobile for Android stopped working

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, deep-linking, android-deep-link

Our React Native app has links *to* specific posts within a FB Group.

When the FB Android app was updated on Nov 18, 2022, the links no longer open the FB android app, but instead direct to the FB mobile web site.  The iOS links are still fine.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and found a workaround?

I opened a report to Facebook, and searched FB community forums but haven't found anyone yet with the same issue.